# AWS ElasticBeanstalk LoadBalancer Config Not Linking my aplication to my domain

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created an aplication but Its is not linked to my domain
exp: "site.com", "www.site.com", when I access it I get: [image]

I need to make my ElasticBeanstalk application connect to my domain (jamelaumn.com) im the owner

here's my application loadbalancer prints:

[image: Errors in my enviroment]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]
[image: 5]

currently I have no rules on EB LB

**My EC2 LoadBalancer:**:
[image: PORT80]
[image: EC2 LOADBALANCER PORT 443]

Comment: You keep posting the same (or nearly same) issue every day. Your question, just like before, is not clear. Thus its gets noaanswers.

Comment: I deleted that application and created a new one, why is my load balancer page different?

Comment: and the issue is that my application it's not in my domain

Comment: I don't know. As I said, its not clear what you are even doing.

Comment: I search for yt videos and i try everything, i will try going to documentation but i did nothing speacial did created the application, did deploy, and put ssl in loadbalancer I dont know what is there more to do

Comment: I will ask again, as I asked before. What is www.jameluna.com? This is your company? You are actually the owner of that domain or at least someone who controls it?

Comment: im the owner of the domain, I want to put my projects to build a portfolio right now im uploading my "django store project" (only the back end matters since im not a good designer)

Comment: Ok. Did you buy it using  AWS Route53?

Comment: and I need to add as https because im utlizing stripe for credit card transactions, and it only works in https

Comment: I did not buy trough Route53 im utilizing hostinger

Comment: and if possible I do  not have intention utilizing route53 Because it costs too much, and I will only utilize the site as portfolio, so it's not a complex thing like a big ecommerce

Comment: Its fine. How did you setup your DNS records on hostinger? Do they point to your EB url?

Comment: I utilized e-mail confirmation insted to manually config the DNS in the certificate manager, in EB i did nothing else, but I did point my EC2 Loadbalancer instance to my DNS as the subdomain "api" it works (actually working, api.jamelaumn.com)

Comment: I mean. In your hostinger, you have to modify your DNS records to point your domain `www.jameluna.com`  to EB URL. If you are not going to do this, nothing will work.

Comment: okay I will send print of my DNS in the question, can you tell me where to put it?

Comment: I've never used hostinger. Please have a look at its docs: https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/1583249-how-to-manage-my-dns-records-at-hostinger

Comment: im really lost right now, I need to apoint this link right?  [link]*http://jamelaumn.eba-ynx2zqp4.sa-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/)

Comment: Ok. I see now. Give me few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments and your updates. I see two issues.

1. SSL certificate is setup for `jamelaumn.com`. This will not work. It must be setup for `*.jamelaumn.com` or `api.jamelaumn.com`. So you have to make new SSL certificate and add it to your ALB.
2. You have to redirect port 80 (http) to 443 (https) on your load balancer. The process is described in [How can I redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS using an Application Load Balancer?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/)

Comment: the 2 there's an issue, im utilizing Classic Load Balancer Listener and the method you sent me it's utilizing  Application Load Balancer, I need to change it but dont know how,

about the first one, I will be recreating right now my certificate

Comment: and about the second one im follwing this documentation with the classic load balancer: (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html)

Comment: I changed my certificate to *.jamelaumn.com but still not working

Comment: @KaynanKaynanFelipeRodrigues Classic load balacer can't do any redirections. You have to use ALB.

Comment: how do I change it

Comment: @KaynanKaynanFelipeRodrigues In EB console you can change type of your LB.

Comment: cant finde where

Comment: im looking everywhere

Comment: @KaynanKaynanFelipeRodrigues So recreate your EB. You need ALB, for redirecting http to https.

Comment: is there a difference between EC2 LoadBalancer and ElasticBeanstalk LoadBalancer? because what I need to, is to Use my ElastiCBeanstalk Enviroment to forward the application to an https domain(my domain)